# Windows10 laptop completely blank screen after powering on but works with external monitor, linux grub boot works fine

Tags: linux, windows-10, display, grub

Been having this problem for a while now but still none the wiser. So essentially I've run a dual boot system with ubuntu and windows for a while now, however in the last few weeks or so I've had trouble booting to windows. It had got to the point where my laptop would boot to only linux.

I've hooked my laptop to an external monitor and I can boot and use windows fine using the grub bootloader menu. I've uninstalled and installed the latest graphics driver and run any windows updaters but now I'm at a loss at what could be causing the problem. Has anyone ran into this problem before? I've checked i'm not booting in safe mode or anything as from my searches that was a issue for other people.

I'm running an acer-aspire-f5, about 2 years old. One of the hinge's half snapped about 6 months ago, but the lid opens and shuts fine enough and haven't had any problems with it.

Comment: Just to confirm, Ubuntu works correctly in both the internal and external monitors but Windows only with the external one?

Comment: Yeah that's correct. I've set the ubuntu to default boot, so it runs after the 10 second lag time. But I don't see the grub menu or acer splash logo, unless it's hooked to the external monitor.

Comment: So,  apparently the internal monitor is defective?

Comment: hmm yeah perhaps but would linux booting (i'm writing this via my laptop) not rule out this? I'm not too wised up on the component side of computing. Could my laptop monitor be defective for windows for be working fine for my ubuntu?

Comment: Do you mean both monitors work in Ubuntu after booting? If so, what happens in Windows if you select the internal only, or disconnect the external (better not try this if the connection is VGA, but if HDMI no problem)?

Comment: Yeah the external monitor just mirrors the ubuntu internal one. It's a HDMI i'm using, if I unplug the external just goes off and the internal remains blank

Comment: I don't know what to suggest other than reset or reinstall Windows.

Comment: Think that's going to be my last ditch option if I can't find anything soon. Thank you for your help anyhow!